# allocating an object of type abstract class c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make and array of size_t size of type Media which has a virtual method, in class MediaManager
but it is giving me this error
[image]

But I have implemented that virtual function in all sub classes, e.g Book is subclass of Media
[image]

MediaManager is just a class that act as a container to all type of Media.
here is my Media class
[image]

Here is MediaManager class, I want to initialize that Pointer to Media object array in Constructor to given size.
[image]

can you tell me please, what am i doing wrong.

I am trying to make array of type Media in MediaManager constructor, that would hold any type of Media,
and then I could use that array for further process.
I cannot use vector because question ask to must use array.

Comment: 1. Don't paste screenshots, paste text. 2. Any class that has a pure virtual function cannot be constructed, that's why it's called an [abstract class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class).

Comment: Abstract classes (specified as having at least one pure virtual function) cannot be instantiated.  Your error is expecting to instantiate an abstract class (in your case, dynamically allocate an array of such a class).    Overriding all pure virtual functions in derived class allows creating instances of those derived classes - it doesn't somehow allow the abstract base class to be instantiated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Media[size]()` is asking for an array of Media.  But Media is an abstract base class which cannot be constructed.  So you need to make an array of pointers to Media, like `new std::unique_ptr<Media>[size]`.  Then you can populate the pointers in that array with things like `std::make_unique<Book>()`.

Comment: I did what you told, but no IDE says                                                                  `Flexible array member 'media' of type 'std::unique_ptr<Media>[]' with non-trivial destruction`                                                                                                                     I changed member of MediaManager class to  std::unique_ptr<Media> media[]; and made changes in constructors as you told.

Comment: @GhulamTahir: You must specify the array size, like `std::unique_ptr<Media>[40]` if you want to hold up to 40 Media instances per MediaManager.